# value map is not a member of Branch[Int]

Tags: scala

I have following ADT:

```
import cats.Functor

sealed trait Tree[+A]

final case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]

final case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
```

and do implementation in the functor:

```
implicit def treeFunctor = new Functor[Tree] {
  def map[A, B](fa: Tree[A])(f: (A) => B): Tree[B] =
    fa match {
      case Branch(left, right) => Branch(map(left)(f), map(right)(f))
      case Leaf(v) => Leaf(f(v))
    }
}
```

and uses it as follow:

```
val b = Branch(left = Branch(Branch(Leaf(5), Leaf(3)), Leaf(10)), Leaf(45))
val functorTree = Functor[Tree].map(b)((v) => v * 4)
```

But following:

```
Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)).map(_ * 2)
```

I've got the compiler error:

```
Error:(21, 29) value map is not a member of A$A90.this.Branch[Int]
Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)).map(_ * 2)
                           ^
```

My question is why do I get the error?

Comment: I'm following the *Scala with Cats* book and had exactly the same problem. The thing is that Scala assigns type `Branch` instead of `Tree` to the variable and since the functor is not covariant, so to speak (not sure if it would be technically correct), it operates only on `Trees`, not `Branches`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `treeFunctor` gives you an instance of `Functor[Tree]` for any `Tree`, but that doesn't mean that any `Tree` is automatically converted to it. It's just that for any `Tree`, you have an implicit instance of `Functor[Tree]` in the scope.

This implicit instance has a method `map` which takes two parameters: instance of `Functor[Tree]` to map over, and the mapping function itself.

So this should work:

```
implicitly[Functor[Tree]].map(Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)))(_ * 2)
```

or simply

```
Functor[Tree].map(Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)))(_ * 2)
```

(since scalaz and cats usually have this convenience apply() for type classes)

*EDIT: When reading your question, I missed the `Functor[Tree].map(b)((v) => v * 4)` part. So what you're actually interested in is the following part.*

If you want to keep your syntax for invoking `map`, you can create an implicit class as a wrapper:

```
implicit class toTreeFunctor[A](tree: Tree[A]) {
  def map[B](f: A => B) = Functor[Tree].map(tree)(f)
}

Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)).map(_ * 2)
```

As pointed out by @P. Frolov, you can get this implicit conversion for free from `import scalaz.syntax.functor._` or `import cats.syntax.functor._`, but note that you have to explicitly upcast your `Branch` to be an instance of `Tree`.

Comment: The type of `val b = Branch(left = Branch(Branch(Leaf(5), Leaf(3)), Leaf(10)), Leaf(45))` is Branch[Int] and why can I pass `b` to implicit `map` function of instance `Functor[Tree]`?

Comment: @zero_coding Because at that point you are passing it to `Functor[Tree]` directly, which is the same as `implicitly[Functor[Tree]]` (not always, but scalaz and cats often have this convenience apply() method for typeclasses). So that works. But you can't invoke `map` upon a `Tree`, only upon a `Functor[Tree]` (and you were trying to do the former by `Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)).map(_ * 2)`). If you add `toTreeFunctor`, your Tree will automatically be converted to Functor[Tree] and it will be OK.

Comment: @zero_coding To be honest, I didn't even notice that you already had the `Functor[Tree].map` part until you mentioned it now in the comment :) so feel free to ignore the first half of my answer (with `implicitly`, since it does the same as your `Functor[Tree].map`).

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Cats, you can `import cats.syntax.functor._` in order to get your `map`. Note that you need to convert branch into the base type, because `Functor` instance is defined for `Tree`, not just a separate `Branch`. You can use type annotation or smart constructors in companion object to do so.

```
import cats.Functor
import cats.syntax.functor._

sealed trait Tree[+A]
final case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
final case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]

implicit def treeFunctor = new Functor[Tree] {
  def map[A, B](fa: Tree[A])(f: (A) => B): Tree[B] =
    fa match {
      case Branch(left, right) => Branch(map(left)(f), map(right)(f))
      case Leaf(v) => Leaf(f(v))
    }
}

val tree: Tree[Int] = Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20))
tree.map(_ * 2) // Branch(Leaf(20), Leaf(40))
```

`cats.syntax.functor` is actually just a singleton object that extends a `FunctorSyntax` trait, packing an implicit conversion from the class that implements `Functor` to the wrapper like one in slouc's answer. Wrapper itself, `Functor.Ops`, is generated by a Simulacrum `@typeclass` macro.